# Use XmlSerializer.CanDeserialize() when deserializing from string

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a method that returns object from .xml file
(please don't mind resource usage and naming, it's just an example)

```
public static T FromXMLFile<T>(string filePath)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
    XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
    if(xmlSerializer.CanDeserialize(xmlTextReader))
    {
        object tempObject = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlTextReader );
        xmlTextReader.Close();
        return (T)tempObject;
    }
    else
        return default(T);
}
```

Now I would like to do the same but with with string instead of a file. I came up with something like this (again, simplified example)

```
public static T FromString<T>(string inputString)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    T result;
    try
    {
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(inputString))
        {
            result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        return result;
     }
     catch //temporary solution, finally should stick to .CanDeserialize(xmlTextReader) usage
     {
         return default(T);
     }
}
```

How would I use .CanDeserialize() in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using the `Deserialize(TextReader)` overload, create an `XmlReader` from the `TextReader`, and use that `XmlReader` for both the `Deserialize` and `CanDeserialize` calls:

```
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(inputString))
    using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader))
    {
        if (serializer.CanDeserialize(xmlReader))
        {
            result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }
    }
```

This approach - with both read and write - also allows you to supply additional reader/writer settings for fine-grained control of the API.